# Flutter Android Build Stuck after Upgrading to Android V2

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-build

I am experiencing this issue when I am trying to run my app on an Android Emulator(API 31, Android 12) after upgrading to Android V2:

Normal Run gets Stuck here:

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

Running it with the `flutter run --verbose` gets stuck with the last output being:

```
[   +1 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... (completed in 4.5s)
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\14166\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell echo -n 32cccba394c538fcf9ce787aea14716102705201 >
/data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.flutter_urban_state.sha1
[  +71 ms] executing: C:\Users\14166\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +315 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    02-24 07:38:41.859 E/.apps.wellbein( 7277): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
[  +15 ms] executing: C:\Users\14166\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true
--ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.example.flutter_urban_state/com.example.flutter_urban_state.MainActivity
[+1065 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.flutter_urban_state/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +1 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

**Things I tried that did not work:**

- Clearing the build, cache, and deleting the outputs folder in build and restarting the app again
- Made sure that the package names in AndroinManifest, and MainActivity.kt are exactly the same
- Upgraded my Dart Version, Flutter Version, and All my pub packages
- uninstalled my adb

Flutter doctor doesn't seem to show any errors either.

Comment: I had the same problem, the only thing solved my issue was upgrading to the latest flutter version

Comment: @AkhlaqShah I already have the flutter 2.10.2 which is the latest SDK

Comment: @MoezElahi have you checked your build.gradle if it is set to 31?

Comment: @KeiCredo target and compile SDK are set to 31, min SDK is set to21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a lot of time I was able to fix the issue.

**What I did to fix it:**

- Changed the SDK version in the pubspec.yaml from `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` to   `sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"`
- In my AndroidManifest.Xml moved my manually added <meta-data.../>
  sections to be under the <application.../> tag, where as they were
  included under the <activity.../> tag before

I really hope this answer is useful and will help someone!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For my case I got this issue and it should be coming from a package. The solution for me was to set the android:exported="true" (it was false)

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.lib.MainActivity"
android:label="Example" 
android:exported="true">
```